# Let $A$ be a ring, and $I$ and $J$ are distinct maximal ideals of $A$. Then, $I$ never contains $J^n$ for every positive integer $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a ring, and $I$ and $J$ are distinct maximal ideals of $A$.
Then, $I$ never contains $J^n$ for every positive integer $n$?
I want to figure out contradiction using $J$'s maximality.
But I cannot say $J^n$ contains $J$, so I'm having trouble.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $J^n \subseteq I$. Taking radicals, we get $r(J^n) \subseteq r(I)$. Then we have $J \subseteq r(I)$. We also have $I \subseteq r(I)$, which is just a property of the radical. But, since $I$ and $J$ are maximal, this implies that $I = r(I) = J$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much, but radical keeps order? A⊂B implies r（A）⊂r（B）？

Comment: Yes. Recall that the radical of $I$ in a ring $A$ is the set $\{a\in A\mid a^n\in I \text{ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$}\}$. If $a \in r(I)$, then $a^n \in I$ for some positive integer $n$. If $I \subseteq J$, then $a^n\in J \Rightarrow a\in r(J)$.